# How do I get "distance between eigenvector" or "value of similarity between two face" from eigenface model of OpenCV ? python language

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I use OpenCV 4.1.2, python 3.6 And I use EigenFace model from openCV can I get value of similarity between two face or something else that can give me information to me I can sort similarly of faces. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I believe you're looking to compute the euclidean distance between two faces. I'd suggest you look into `cv2.NORM_L2`. You can do something like this `distance = cv2.norm(img_1, img_2, cv2.NORM_L2)`